# Compound adjectives with articles or not?

Tags: articles, adjectives

Which one is correct?

A **half-a-liter** lemonade bottle

A **half-liter** lemonade bottle

Is it true that 1 is wrong?

Comment: I have half a liter of lemonade. I have a half-liter bottle. No wrong but not precise or great.

Comment: Hmm... I have half a liter of lemonade - doesn't mention a bottle. So, you think that 1 is grammatically correct?

Comment: I no longer answer questions that are repeated.

Comment: You definition "not precise or great" is not clear-cut as it's not clear whether it's grammatically correct. If it's correct then why is it not precise or great?

Answer (score 3):

The first is wrong - the correct form is "a half-litre bottle".

Comment: Thank you! IS it also "an hour-and-a-half walk" or "an hour-and-half walk"? I suppose it must be "an hour-and-half walk". Right?

Comment: No, it is "an hour and a half", but I'd prefer "a ninety minute walk"

Comment: Thank you. Don't you think it's not very consistent? A half-a-liter - wrong. an hour and a half - correct. Any idea why?

Comment: You'd say "a litre and a half bottle"  though actually you'd say "a one point five litre bottle."  And you'd say "A half hour walk" (or probably "a thirty minute walk")